# How to bring non-EU parents to live in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

My dream was to live in the UK and work there, but when I checked I cannot bring my mom to the UK, and without this option, I cannot leave as she has no other family who can care for her. She is still healthy though, so I don't think she qualifies as an elderly dependent visa.

Please could someone help give me some insight on how I can fulfil my goal without leaving my mom behind in Tokyo?

Comment: Hello Anna, I believe that this question belongs to Expatriates.SE, not Travel.SE.

Comment: @Anna this does indeed belong on [Expatriates.SE].  When you post there, please mention whether you have EU citizenship and whether your mother is dependent on you.

Comment: By 'dependent', is she financially dependent on you? Do you pay more than half of her living expenses?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, apologizes! I will ask inside the correct category suggested!